# The Events Calendar RSVP ticket number control - padding not taking effect

Tags: css

At [this page](http://www.thesmallbusinesslounge.com.au/event/smartphone-ography-workshop/) there is a form control to increase or decrease the number of tickets a customer would like to RSVP to. The +/- control is not respecting the padding of

```
<td class="tribe-ticket quantity buttons_added" data-product-id="11866">
```

in

```
<td class="tribe-ticket quantity buttons_added" data-product-id="11866"><input type="button" value="-" class="minus">
  <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="11866">
  <input type="number" class="tribe-ticket-quantity" min="0" max="20" name="quantity_11866" value="0">
  <span class="tribe-tickets-remaining"> 20 out of 20 available </span>
  <input type="button" value="+" class="plus"></td>

<style>
.tribe-tickets-rsvp .tribe-ticket.quantity {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    display: block;
    padding: 16px 10px 8px;
}
</style>
```

The +/- control needs to respect the padding and move down and leftwards:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyIwq.jpg

Can someone help me achieve this please?

Help appreciated.

Problem is occurring for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.minus, .plus {
    left: 42px;
}
.quantity .plus {
    top: 16px;
}
.quantity .minus {
    top: 38px;
}
```

there's some overlap on hover. you'll have to play with heights (currently 50%) or something else maybe.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it perfectly. Bonus points if you can work out why clicks don't have an effect? :-)

Comment: Playing with z-index might do it. (Puts elements in a top-to-bottom order so the clickable one is at the top.)